# Definition of semiquantitative

Tags: statistics, definitions, measurement

I'd like to understand differences between how biologists and statisticians deal with uncertainty. As a concrete example, I'd like to understand if "semi-quantitative" can be defined in terms of statistics and probability. As a first step, I'd very much appreciate any definition (either statistical or not) of "semi-quantitative". What is the distinction between a "quantitative" and "semi-quantitative" method?

Google scholar has many papers including "semi-quantitative" in the title. As an example, I'll quote a portion of the abstract from Marone, M., Mozzetti, S., De Ritis, D. et al. *Semiquantitative RT-PCR analysis to assess the expression levels of multiple transcripts from the same sample*. Biol Proced Online 3, 19–25 (2001). https://doi.org/10.1251/bpo20

> As for all quantitative techniques, great care must be taken in all optimization steps: the necessary controls to ensure a rough quantitative (*semi-quantitative*) analysis are described here, together with an example from a study on the effects of TGF-β1 in TF-1 cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Caveat*:
This answer differs fundamentally from that given by @acvill. I have not provided authoritative support for it — it is merely my understanding of the use of the terms in biological science.

The use of the terms **Quantitative** and **Semi-quantitative** in biology refer to measurements, not to statistics, although if the measurements are accurate meaningful statistics can be performed upon them. Nor is the distinction fundamentally to do with accuracy. Both types of measurements can vary in accuracy, depending on the methods used to obtain them.

In the example given, **the problem is to measure the quantity of transcripts** — RNAs of a particular kind (generally specific mRNAs) — that are present in only small quantities.

**Quantitative measurements** of such transcripts would determine one of the following:

- Their number or molarity (molarity)
- Their weight or concentration (grams per litre)

However doing this is difficult in the case of such small quantities of molecules found in a mixture.

**Semi-Quantitative measurements** of transcripts attempt to measure something indirectly related to their concentration, which, while not producing a number, concentration or amount, gives some value related to these that can be used for comparison with other mRNA transcripts.

In this case the mRNA is copied many times by PCR to eventually give an amount of product that can be measured. As far as I can see from the paper it was intensity of staining with ethidium bromide after gel electrophoresis. However it might have been incorporation of radioactivity or amount of some radioactive probe hybridized to it. In any case the measurement would have arbitrary units which could be used in comparison.

In my opinion it is the fact that the method does not measure the quantity of the mRNA (or whatever) in standard units that makes it semi-quantitative, although the indirectness of the measurement involving several stages can compromise its accuracy.

**Addendum: Definition in relation to Covid antibody tests**

I am wary about talking about a *definition* of ‘semi-quantitative’ because the [definition in the reputable Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/semiquantitative), citing the first use in 1927:

> constituting or involving less than quantitative precision

does not correspond to current biological usage by implying that it relates to the *precision* of measurements. (See, for example, the [Wikipedia entry on Precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision) to see why.)

It is of interest that the [emergency approval by the US Food and Drug Administration](https://www.fda.gov/news-events/press-announcements/coronavirus-covid-19-update-fda-authorizes-first-tests-estimate-patients-antibodies-past-sars-cov-2) of certain SARS-CoV-2 antibody test in late July 2020 specifies explicitly that they are *semi-quantitative*, and the pharmaceutical company, Roche, provides the [following explanation of the term on its website](https://diagnostics.roche.com/us/en/article-listing/qualitative-vs-quantitative-antibody-tests-whats-the-difference.html).

> A qualitative test determines the “if;” quantitative and semi-quantitative tests answer the question “how much?” By measuring the level of SARS-CoV-2 antibodies in a patient’s blood sample, quantitative and semi-quantitative tests give a more definitive answer about the body’s immune response to the virus. *Quantitative tests are traceable to a specific international standard that ensures the result produced correlates to a numeric quantity of antibodies*. Due to the current lack of an international standard, the FDA has not granted EUA to any quantitative tests. Semi-quantitative tests estimate an approximate concentration of SARS-CoV-2 antibodies in a patient’s blood sample, and can be traceable to a specific standard to ensure consistent results.

The italicization is my own to indicate the relationship to my explanation, above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If you have a chance, I'd appreciate hearing a generally applicable definition that captures the key features of what you wrote. Here is one attempt:

*Consider an experiment designed to measure a physical quantity. That measurement is **quantitative** if it can be expressed in the same units as the target physical quantity. All measurements that are not quantitative are **semi-quantitative**.*

I think most people would agree that my attempt needs some modification.

Comment: @rileysg — At present I think your definition is on the lines of my standpoint. However I am wary of definitions. In biology things are always a bit less defined than in the physical sciences. I would like time to look at other examples of usage of the term and its application. One problem with my answer is that you can try to calibrate non-standard units against a standard. Another consideration is that the nature of the assay may be internally consistent and usable for comparison in an individual setup, but the values not transferable to another setup.

Comment: @rileysg — I decided not to go in quite the direction I mentioned when I discovered the recent application of the term to covid antibody testing. This seemed to me of more contemporary general interest.

Answer (score 1):

There is no strict statistical definition of *semi-quantitative*. Generally, a **quantitative** method yields results that can be compared across different experiments, whereas a **qualitative** method yields results for which comparisons are only meaningful between samples within a single experiment. Per your quote, we can see that the authors are using the *semi-* prefix to indicate to readers that the technique has not been fully optimized, and therefore any results obtained by their semi-quantitative method should be interpreted with a grain of salt.

In context of RT-PCR methods, quantitative methods typically undergo rigorous optimization to define necessary controls and a strict parameter set. This should include (1) instrument and reagent specification, (2) constraints on primer / probe design, (3) some measurement of expected experimental error, and, most importantly,  (4) use of a well-defined spike-in or control sample. A control sample or set of samples of known concentration is necessary to back-calculate the nucleic acid copy number for your experimental samples, and any RT-PCR without such a control is necessarily qualitative.

By calling their RT-PCR protocol semi-quantitative, the authors are saying to the reader "Hey, we made this method. We think it's pretty good. We tested some things, but not everything. *Caveat emptor*."

Comment: Thank you! Could you give a reference for your definition? Even if it's simply something you learned by working as a biologist, that would be helpful to know.

Comment: The definitions I give are just my understanding. I am a biologist.

Comment: I think David's answer fits my understanding better, but my bigger quibble with your answer would be the definition of "qualitative". Something qualitative is something that can't be put into numerical representations. It might include comparisons like "more/less" that get closer to "semiquantitative" but also includes things that can't really get any number, like lists of words or semantic relationships.